# How to retrieve user roles along with the token

Tags: keycloak

How to retrieve user roles along with the token in Keycloak in both Angular and Spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build in `User realm role` protocol mapper to add this info to the access token/id token.
You can add a new mapper under a client scope from `Client Scope/your_scope/mappers`:[image]